# What are the differences between File System and SQL Server deployments for SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an SSIS package that needs to be deployed to SQL Server agent.

It has 2 external dependencies (2 assemblies, both installed in the GAC)

Now the package runs just fine under a File System Deployment

but when we deploy to SQL Server agent it fails with 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' within the task that requires 1 of the external dependencies

Just to let you know, this external dependency is an Interop assembly to the right fax com api

What is the main differences between File System deployment and SQL Server deployment. I think if I can understand this a bit more then I may be able to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File system SSIS deployments (the only kind I've done) store SSIS packages as files on the OS. SQL Server deployments, if I have it right, first load the packages to be stored in a "deploymemt-only" file, which is later used to load them back into a different instance of SQL Server. (I don't know what database they're loaded into--in SQL 7.0 and 2000, DTS packages were stored in msdb, so I'd look there first. Maybe undocumented table sysdtspackages?)

Personally, it all looked so darn confusing and hard to maintain over time that I just stuck with files. Weaker security, and I'm not sure what other benefits I'm missing out on, but when updating I just copy over new files and I'm done.

Comment: 2005 and 2008 store it in MSDB, and the File System stores it in `%Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Packages`, FYI.

Comment: it seems as though if I were managing the SSIS packages myself I would go the File system deployment route. But unfortunately I am not the one managing them =(

Comment: Regarding the security issue - we store ours in the database, extract them when needed to the file system, then delete them when the job completes or fails.  Not *entirely* secure but it's one less detail for the customers to have to understand.

Comment: Future me here (July 2020). How SQL Server stores SSIS packages has changed significantly over the past few years. If this topic concerns you, you need to do some serious research--and don't rely on 10+ year old SO posts!

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) can be deployed in two ways: File System Deployment and SQL Server Deployment. Here we’ll see the difference between the these two methods.

File System Deployment:

•The packages are saved on a physical location on the hard disk drive or any shared folder on the network.

•We can easily manage the packages if we want to bring about any changes in it.

•Packages are available when on file system, as there is will be no issue of server being down.

•We can easily load the packages in to the designer.

SQL Server Deployment:

•SSIS packages will be stored in the MSDB database, in the sysssispackages table (we can find this table in the MSDB database under system tables – msdb.dbo.sysssispackages). We can save the packages in different folders if we want, these folders being virtual folders. Here the SSIS package will not be stored as a physical file rather it will be on the MSDB database.

•Packages can be easily accessed by multiple individuals when saved on SQL Server.

•It is more secure as compared to File System, as it gets the same benefits as Database security.

•We can have the packages backed up while taking backup of the databases.

•We can filter the packages using SQL Server queries using the sysssispackages table.